# Need help returning data in defined buckets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @dateto as datetime
set @dateto='8/1/11'

SELECT     ti.userkey, SUM(l.Price * l.OrderQty) AS SumOfOrders, count (distinct ti.orderid) AS Ordercount
FROM         SOLine AS l WITH (nolock) LEFT OUTER JOIN
             SOImported AS ti ON ti.OrderId = l.OrderId LEFT OUTER JOIN
             Sale AS o ON o.SaleId = ti.Inventory_Id
  Where ti.createddate < @DateTo                
 GROUP BY ti.userkey, o.WootSiteId
```

Need this query to bucket order count like the following:

```
Group          userkeycount   sumoforders
 1 trans
 2-30
 31-60
 61-90
 91-120
 121-150
 151-180
 181-210
 211-240
 241-270
 271-300
 301-330
 331-360
 360 or More
```

Comment: Suggestion: create a table with the lower and upper limits for each bucket. To be clear, *two* columns per row (bucket). `JOIN` to this table e.g. `T1.param_value BETWEEN Buckets.lower_limit AND Buckets.upper_limit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @dateto as datetime
set @dateto='8/1/11'

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Ordercount >= 360 THEN '360 or More'
         WHEN Ordercount = 1 THEN '1 trans'
         ELSE CAST (30 * FLOOR(Ordercount / 30) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST (30 * CEILING (Ordercount / 30) AS VARCHAR)
    END grp,
    COUNT(*) userkeycount,
    SUM(SumOfOrders) SumOfOrders
FROM (
    SELECT ti.userkey,
        SUM(l.Price * l.OrderQty) AS SumOfOrders,
        count (distinct ti.orderid) AS Ordercount
    FROM         SOLine AS l WITH (nolock) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 SOImported AS ti ON ti.OrderId = l.OrderId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 Sale AS o ON o.SaleId = ti.Inventory_Id
     Where ti.createddate < @DateTo
     GROUP BY ti.userkey
) rs
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Ordercount >= 360 THEN '360 or More'
         WHEN Ordercount = 1 THEN '1 trans'
         ELSE CAST (30 * FLOOR(Ordercount / 30) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST (30 * CEILING (Ordercount / 30) AS VARCHAR)
    END
```

Comment: Thank you.  when I run, I get this error.  sorry newbie at this but want to learn

Comment: Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: @tom-doe Try removing the `o.WootSiteId` from the inner group by. Or try the updated answer

Comment: You are truly a master.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in The Scrum Meister's query... below you can see the result.

```
create table #T (ID int identity(0,1) primary key, Ordercount int)

insert #T (Ordercount) values (1)
insert #T (Ordercount) values (2)
insert #T (Ordercount) values (5)
insert #T (Ordercount) values (30)
insert #T (Ordercount) values (37)
insert #T (Ordercount) values (60)
insert #T (Ordercount) values (61)
insert #T (Ordercount) values (360)
insert #T (Ordercount) values (361)


select Ordercount,
CASE WHEN Ordercount > 360 THEN '360 or More'
         WHEN Ordercount = 1 THEN '1 trans'
         WHEN Ordercount <= 30 THEN '2-30'
         ELSE 
         CAST (30*FLOOR(case when Ordercount%30 = 0 then Ordercount-1 else Ordercount end/30)+1 AS VARCHAR) 
         + '-' + 
         CAST (30*FLOOR(case when Ordercount%30 = 0 then Ordercount-1 else Ordercount end/30)+30 AS VARCHAR)
    END
from #T
```